# Get and show the order of jQuery sortable array in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, laravel, jquery-ui-sortable

I use jQuery sortable to sort pages slug from a table to create menu and save an array with these items.

Table Pages

id  |      slug

4   |       slug-1

7   |       slug-2

```js
$('#pages_selection').sortable({
        items               : 'li:not(.empty)',
        connectWith         : '#pages_available, #pages_selection',
        placeholder         : 'sort-highlight',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        zIndex              : 999999,
        update: function(event, ui) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{ URL::route('menusaveAjax') }}",
                data: {
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'id_menu': {{ $menu->id }},
                    'content': $('#pages_selection').sortable('toArray', {attribute: 'key'})
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My list :

```html
<ul class="todo-list" id="pages_selection">
   <li id="0" class="sort-highlight empty text-center">
      <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down"></i> Drop here
   </li>             
   @foreach($selections as $k => $v)
   <li id="{{ $v }}" key="{{ $k }}">
     <span class="handle">
       <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
       <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
     </span>
     <span class="text">Page {{ $k }}</span>
   </li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

In database this is stored like this : ["slug-2","slug-1"]

Now I want to create my menu so my logic is :

1. Request from the header menu for example in menus table
2. Retrieve datas of this from pages table
3. Create menu in the order defined in menu table, in array.

So this is what I do:

```php
$menu = MyMenu::where('name', 'header')->first();
$items = $menu->content
//Show $items
array:2 [▼
 0 => "slug-2"
 1 => "slug-1"
]
$pages = Page::whereIn('slug', $menu->content)->get(['id','title', 'slug'])->toArray();
//Show $pages
array:2 [▼
 0 => array:3 [▼
   "id" => 4
   "title" => "Slug 1"
   "slug" => "slug-1"
 ]
 1 => array:3 [▼
   "id" => 7
   "title" => "Slug 2"
   "slug" => "slug-2"
 ]
]
```

**The problem is :** If a create my menu, my items are not in the order saved in database(["slug-2","slug-1"]) but in order of ids...

I want this :

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/slug-2">Slug 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/slug-1">Slug 1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But i have this :

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/slug-1">Slug 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/slug-2">Slug 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

How can do this ? I think I have to manipulate my arrays, but I don't know how...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, but not tested

Reverse the array before sending the AJAX response using array_reverse($array, true);